# Firebase Crashlytics amount of recorded non-fatal exceptions

Tags: firebase, crashlytics-android

I have a question about recording non fatal exceptions from an android application. The documentation says that "Crashlytics only stores the most recent eight recorded exceptions. If your app throws more than eight exceptions, older exceptions are lost." I don't understand if it stores 8 different non-fatal exceptions, or 8 instances of some non-fatal exception. Additionally, looking at my crashlytics, I see much more than 8 non-fatal exceptions. Does this limit apply then only to custom non-fatal exceptions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

"Stores" refers to the client app. It only stores 8 instances of exceptions locally until they are uploaded to the server. Once the app has been able to connect and upload these to the servers, they are purged locally and more can be generated.

The idea here is that for any given crash event, you are only going to get at most 8 errors reported on that, and if the device is offline for some time, Crashlytics won't eat up storage and memory for non-fatals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, if the device is online, then the client app reports all the non-fatals in real time and does not store them locally?